# How can I use ddply inside a function?

Tags: r, plyr

I am struggling using ddly() inside a function. The following hopefully illustrates what I am trying to accomplish:

```
library(plyr)
dat <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(10), g = rep(1:2, 5))
dat

## Works for a particular variable "var1"
ddply(dat, .(g), summarize, m.ll = t.test(var1)$conf.int[1])

## ... but not inside a function
myddply <- function(x){
    res <- ddply(dat, .(g), summarize, m.ll = t.test(x)$conf.int[1])
    return(res)
}
myddply(x = "var1")
```

I thought `eval(parse(...))` would work, but to no avail.

```
myddply <- function(x){
    res <- ddply(dat, .(g), summarize, m.ll = t.test(eval(parse(text = x)))$conf.int[1])
    return(res)
}
myddply(x = "var1")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `summarize` for this:

```
myddply <- function(x){
  res <- ddply(dat, .(g), 
                 function(df) setNames(t.test(df[,x])$conf.int[1], "m.ll"))
  return(res)
}
```

Comment: `c(m.ll = t.test(df[[x]])$conf.int[1])` would be a little simpler